# Why has HTML Button with Background Image an UGLY rendering?

Tags: html, css, button, background-image, imagebutton

```
<input type="button" value="Nice" />
<input type="button" value="Ugly"
style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8lk7.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left center;
padding-left:150px;
height:160px" />
```

Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/pbgmzp7j/

Is there a workaround?

Comment: yes, add your own styles. youre free to style it any way you want to begin with add a `border: 1px solid #color;` , `border-radius: 3px;` and `background-color: #fff;`

Comment: I dont want to style the button in a specific way. I like to have the original browser style, exactly like the "Nice" button.

Comment: The don't put all that style and just take the code of your "nice" button and change the text...

Answer (score 2):

Try it without the input and use button

```
<button>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8lk7.png"/>
</button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Gr/pbgmzp7j/4/)

Comment: Nice sollution Thanks. Unfortunatelly I have to do it with JSF1.4. I must figure how that works there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
```

or you can use any color in bg. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pbgmzp7j/2/)

Comment: Actually I like to have the original button style. Why is this ugly rendering happening?

Answer (score 0):

use:

css `border:none;` [***DEMO***](https://jsfiddle.net/pbgmzp7j/1/)

```
<input type="button" value="Nice" />
<input type="button" value="Ugly" style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8lk7.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:left center; padding-left:150px; height:160px; border:none;" />
```

**UPDATE:**

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/pbgmzp7j/3/)

Comment: Actually I like to have the original button style. Why is this ugly rendering happening?